# How to combine effect size and uncertainty in one measure?

Tags: effect-size, uncertainty, measurement

The p-value and posterior probability measure the level of certainty in a particular outcome such as "the web traffic to variant A is greater than that to variant B." Of course these measures tell you nothing about the effect size, such as, "how much bigger is the web traffic to A than B?" Ideally you should measure both the size of the effect and the certainty. Suppose I want to compute a score for each of n variants of a website that incorporates information about both the size of the differences among the variants, and the uncertainty thereof. I have considered simply multiplying the posterior probability of an effect of interest by the expectation of the effect. Is this valid? Are there better ways to construct a score that incorporates both certainty and effect size? Thank you.

Comment: There are cases when the effect is huge but the p-value is small, and the opposite can happen too. Trying to combine the two in some sense amounts to going from frequentism to Bayesian, i.e., you believe there is a continuum of truth with some probability distribution. In that framework, you can simply take the expected value of the effect size.

Comment: That would be convenient as I am already working in the Bayesian framework! My trouble with using the expectation alone, however, is that you are not incorporating the dispersion of the estimate into your score. I guess from an expected utility standpoint it makes sense though.

Comment: An alternative I just thought about would be a sort of Bayesian Cohen's d, where you divide the expected effect by its dispersion. If your interest is in finite population inference, you could compute the "Cohen's d" from posterior predictions rather than the population estimands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that a p-value "tells you nothing about effect size! It tells you roughly how large the effect size is when scaled by the variability. Yes, it is a non-linear scale and it goes down as the observed effect size goes up, and its relationship to the naturally scaled effect size will vary with the type of test, but none of those things mean that it communicates nothing about the observed effect size. Despite that protestation I will say that no-one should ever provide a p-value without a much more directly interpretable index or measure of the observed effect size.

Even if it were possible to combine effect size information and uncertainty information in a more readily interpreted index, I think that that would be a bad idea. The effect size and the uncertainty of measurement are different things, have different scales, different units. Any combination would reduce the communicated information. Any advantage of concision would be more than offset by a loss of precision, in my opinion.

I think if you run a few calculations with varying effect sizes and posterior probability distributions you will see how hard to interpret your proposed score would be. I expect that any other score would be just as bad.